# How to secure an Amazon S3 URL

Tags: security, apache, url, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

I'm quite new to Amazon S3 and looking for a way to secure large amount of data on s3 that will be accessed by users via our website.

The issue I have is that I don't want the data on Amazon s3 to be public at all so it need sto be private but still accessible via our site.

Presigning each url request would be a pain due to the amount of new files being accessed and added all the time. I know there is option `http_referer` mod, should be
quick and easy, and maybe in combination with very obscure URLs
(long random codes in the path) that might be enough?

Is there any other way to make s3 urls secure?

Cheers

Comment: What do you mean by "securing". Do you want to limit the viewing to just one user. Do you want people to be able to prevent copy/pasting of images?

Comment: @James C I just what to only allow the content on S3 to be access via a url from our website here

Comment: do you have a fixed office IP address? if so why not just lock it down to accesses from that IP address?

Comment: @James C but it will need to be accessed via public IP on the website so security is very sensitive

Answer (score 10, accepted):

S3 does provide the ability to sign an image so that the URL is only valid for a limited period of time. There are more details of that [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html#RESTAuthenticationQueryStringAuth)

There are a number of ways of handling access as described [here](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingAuthAccess.html)